# REST and Slim 3 : why CSRF check failed with post method?

Tags: php, ajax, rest, slim, slim-3

I want to add a user with REST API on a web application created with Slim3.
I use the same route on application to add a user and it's works.
But by an ajax request since an other website I have "400 bad request" because of CSRF check failed.
Before this request I do a GET method to get CSRF token and build hidden input with CSRF token data. Then I give CSRF token at POST method but it doesn't work... I don't understand.

Thanks.

Ajax Get Method :

```
$.get("https://extranet.exemple.fr/api/token", {})
            .done(function (data, text, jqxhr) {
                if (data.success === true) {
                    $("#csrf_name").val(data.csrf.csrf_name);
                    $("#csrf_value").val(data.csrf.csrf_value);
                }
            })
            .fail(function (jqxhr) {})
            .always(function () {});
            });
```

Ajax POST :

```
var csrfname = $("#csrf_name").val();
var csrfvalue = $("#csrf_value").val();
var objajaxargs = {
                    dataUser: dataUser,
                    csrf_name: csrfname,
                    csrf_value: csrfvalue,
                };
                $.post("https://extranet.exemple.fr/user/add", objajaxargs)
                    .done(function (data, text, jqxhr) {
                        if (data.success === true) {
                            alert("success");
                        }
                    })
                    .fail(function (jqxhr) {})
                    .always(function () {});
```

In my container

```
$container["csrf"] = function ($container) {
    return new \Slim\Csrf\Guard();
};
```

Slim GET method

```
$app->get('/api/token', function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response, $args) use ($app) {

$container = $app->getContainer();
// Generate new token and update request
$request = $container->csrf->generateNewToken($request);
// Build Header Token
$nameKey = $container->csrf->getTokenNameKey();
$valueKey = $container->csrf->getTokenValueKey();
$name = $request->getAttribute($nameKey);
$value = $request->getAttribute($valueKey);
$tokenArray = [
    $nameKey => $name,
    $valueKey => $value
];

$respCSRF["success"] = false;
if (!empty($tokenArray)) {
    $respCSRF["success"] = true;
    $respCSRF["csrf"] = $tokenArray;
}

return $response->withJson($respCSRF);});
```

Slim POST method

```
$app->post("/user/add", function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response, $args) use ($app) {

$container = $app->getContainer();
$objBody = $request->getParsedBody();
$objUser = new \App\Models\UserModel($container);

foreach ($objBody["dataUser"] as $key => $value) {
    $objAdherent->$key = $value;
}

$arrJsonResponse = ["success" => false];

if (filter_var($objUser->mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
    $infosAdd = $objUser->addUser();
    if ($infosAdd !== false) {
        $arrJsonResponse["success"] = true;
        return $response->withJson($arrJsonResponse)->withStatus(201);
    }
} 

return $response->withJson($arrJsonResponse)->withStatus(400);});
```

Comment: Maybe the Ajax client makes a [CORS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) (OPTION). Can you check that?

Comment: @DanielO. : I have this before :
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
 return $response;
});
$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
 $response = $next($req, $res);
 return $response
  ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://www.exemple.fr')
  ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
  ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
});

Comment: I found this on [https://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/enable-cors.html](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/enable-cors.html)

Comment: Please try this middleware instead (just for testing purpose): http://discourse.slimframework.com/t/cors-slim-preflight-request-fails/1992/6?u=odan

Comment: thank you but sorry this middleware does not solve my problem.

Comment: I activate token persistence mode with $guard->setPersistentTokenMode(true); and it's work :)

Answer (score 3):

I resolve my problem. I set csrf token persistence at true and it's works!

Solution:

```
 /**
 * Init CSRF
 * @return \Slim\Csrf\Guard
 */
$container["csrf"] = function ($container) {
    $guard = new \Slim\Csrf\Guard();
    $guard->setPersistentTokenMode(true);
    return $guard;
};
```

Comment: If you have pages that rely a lot in AJAX calls this is a must!