# Failed CSRF check! in postman when trying POST method (API with slim 3)

Tags: rest, csrf, slim, slim-3

I am working with a Slim 3 project and I installed the [CSRF package](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Csrf) ("slim/csrf": "^0.8.2",)

In order to make POSTs request I am using postman. When sending the action I get the following error:

> Failed CSRF check!

Here are my API routes (in this case, focus on the POST route):

```
<?php

/* RESTful endpoints or routes */

use App\Controllers\api\users\UserController;

    $app->group('/api',function () use ($app){
        $app->group('/users', function () {
            $this->get('', UserController::class.':index');
            $this->get('/{id}', UserController::class.':show');
            $this->post('', UserController::class.':store');
        });
    });
```

Here is the controller supposed to get the info from the POST request where I get the error:

```
//Save a user via API
    public function store($request,$response,$args)
    {
        //todo: validation!
        var_dump($request->getParams());//todo: CSRF check failed!
        die();
    }
```

Here is where I registered the CSRF component:

```
//Register the CSRF Component
$container['csrf'] = function ($container){
    return new \Slim\Csrf\Guard();
};
```

I tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48266488/1883256 but it didn't work.

Is there any workaround to make it work? How do I prevent the CSRF to run on my API routes?

*** Solved ***

As [Zamrony P. Juhara](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50195881/1883256) suggested, I decided to apply CSRF to the web routes except for the APIs routes.

Grouping all my web routes:

```
    $app->group('',function ()use($app,$container){
        /* ******* H O M E ********** */
        require __DIR__ . '/web/home/home.php';
        /* ********** T O P I C  s ********** */
        require __DIR__ . '/web/topics/topics.php';

        /* ********** C O N T A C T *********** */
        require __DIR__ . '/web/contact/contact.php';

/* And so on and etcetera ....*/
        /* ********************************************************************************* */
    })->add($container->get('csrf'));//Adding CSRF protection only for web routes
```

And, for example, inside the `topics.php` routes file I have:

```
$app->group('/topics',function(){
    $this->get('',TopicController::class.':index');
    $this->get('/{id}',TopicController::class.':show')->setName('topics.show');
});
```

And as for the API routes, they stay the same.

Finally, inside my container I commented the following:

```
//$app->add($container->get('csrf')); //I've commented this line in order to add CSRF for specific routes (all except APIs ones)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you add `Slim\Csrf\Guard` middleware to route or application (if you want to apply csrf for all routes). For example

To apply csrf middleware to all routes

```
$csrf = $container->csrf;
$app->add($csrf);
```

or to apply for certain routes only

```
$csrf = $container->csrf;
$app->group('/api',function () use ($app, $csrf){
    $app->group('/users', function () {
        $this->get('', UserController::class.':index')
             ->add($csrf);
        $this->get('/{id}', UserController::class.':show');
        $this->post('', UserController::class.':store')
             ->add($csrf);
    });
});
```

You also need to make sure that there are Csrf token name/value data passed with request. When you use Postman, you need to find a way to obtain token name key/value pair before execute POST.

Following code is excerpt from [Slim Csrf Readme](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Csrf).

```
// CSRF token name and value
$nameKey = $this->csrf->getTokenNameKey();
$valueKey = $this->csrf->getTokenValueKey();
$name = $request->getAttribute($nameKey);
$value = $request->getAttribute($valueKey);

// Render HTML form which POSTs to /bar with two hidden input fields for the
// name and value:
// <input type="hidden" name="<?= $nameKey ?>" value="<?= $name ?>">
// <input type="hidden" name="<?= $valueKey ?>" value="<?= $value ?>">
```

Read [Slim Csrf Readme](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Csrf) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to follow your first approach: apply CSRF for certain routes only. Check my answer edit for more details.